# How do I make this function go to Players instead of Workspace

Tags: lua, roblox

The thing I'm trying to do here is that when the player touches this randomly spawning ball it adds to his leaderstats score.

```lua
local spawned = 0

while true do
    if spawned >= 5 then
        break
    end
    local Randombumber1 = math.random(1, 30)
    local Randombumber2 = math.random(1, 30)
    spawned = spawned + 1
    wait(3)
    
    local PointBall = Instance.new("Part", workspace)

    PointBall.Size = Vector3.new(1,1,1)
    PointBall.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("White")
    PointBall.Material = "Neon"
    PointBall.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball -- Makes it a sphere
    PointBall.Anchored = true -- Anchors the part so it doesn't move
    PointBall.CanCollide = false -- Makes it so that players can walk through the ball
    PointBall.Position = Vector3.new(Randombumber1,3,Randombumber2)
    
    
    PointBall.Touched:Connect(function(player)
        local PlayerPoints = player.Parent.leaderstats.Dookie
        PlayerPoints.Value = PlayerPoints.Value + 1
        PointBall:Destroy()
    end)
end
```

The error message is leaderstats is not a valid member of Model "Workspace.ASWXDYC2"
I want it to go to the player in the Players thing, any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`PointBall.Touched:Connect(function(player)` This function will simply respond with the part that touched the `PointBall`. This part is of course in the `Workspace` hence why it isn't working. We have to get the player from the Players folder.

To fix this we have the `GetPlayerFromCharacter()` function, then we can apply the leaderstats change.

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

PointBall.Touched:Connect(function(hitPart)
    local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hitPart.Parent)
    local PlayerPoints = player.leaderstats.Dookie
    PlayerPoints.Value = PlayerPoints.Value + 1
    PointBall:Destroy()
end)
```

Comment: Since `Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter()` can return `nil` it's always a good idea to add safety checks. `if not player then return end` is a great way to ensure that your code doesn't throw errors when other non-character objects trigger the Touch event.